# Qué driver tengo que utilizar lanzar un test Selenium en C# con el navegador Edge Cromium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, edge

Estoy intentando lanzar un sencillo test de selenium en C# con el navegador Edge, pero no lo consigo. El error que me indica es el siguiente:

> OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: 'The file C:\Selenium\Drivers\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe does not exist. The driver can be downloaded at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=619687

Ésta es la linea de código que me da el error:

`driver = new EdgeDriver("C:\\Selenium\\Drivers");`

En la ruta `C:\Selenium\Drivers` tengo el siguiente driver: **msedgedriver.exe**

Descargado de la página:
*https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/*

Ese driver se corresponde con la versión que tengo del Edge:

> Microsoft Edge está actualizado.
>   Versión 80.0.361.62 (Compilación oficial) (64 bits)

¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal? ¿Cuál es mi error?

Gracias

Comment: Si las versiones del navegador y del driver son correctas, tal vez el problema es la version de Selenium que tambien tiene que estar alineada para poder trabajar con esas versiones de Edge. ¿Cual es tu version de Selenium?

Comment: Versión de selenium utilizada 3.141.0

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema esta en esta linea:

```
driver = new EdgeDriver("C:\\Selenium\\Drivers");
```

Debes indicarle tambien el ejecutable:

```
driver = new EdgeDriver("C:\\Selenium\\Drivers\\msedgedriver.exe");
```

Comment: No funciona añadiendo eso